# Regex not working correctly

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regex. It's supposed to match all one character, and also all one character along with a space.

For example:

```
wwwwwwww - MATCH
www wwwwww - MATCH
@@@@@ - MATCH
wwwwqq - NOT MATCH
wwww qqqq - NOT MATCH
```

But it's not matching things like:

```
@@@@@@@
.......
```

What's wrong with it? Here it is below:

```
var match = Regex.Match(message, @"^\s*(\w)(?:\1|\s)*$");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `@` and `.` are not "word characters". Couldn't you just match with `(.)` ?

```
var match = Regex.Match(message, @"^\s*(.)(?:\1|\s)*$");
```

You could also try with `\S` (non white-space character).

Comment: How would I match on not just word characters, but any characters?

Comment: With `.` or `\S`. See in my answer.

Comment: Oh okay I gotcha. Oh I didn't know that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`\w` is shorthand for a "word character," which does not include punctuation like `@` or `.`.

Dot (`.`) signifies any character; `\S` signifies non-whitespace.